# Numbers in texfield

Tags: php, function, trim, data-extraction

there I have this text as a product name (example):
"Lego creator 10270 Car V1 cool"
I need to extract only 10270. for this I have following php function:

```
function my_get_sku( $product_name = "" ) {
     $sku = 0;                       // if no SKU is found, return 0
     $sku_digits = 5;     // change this to the number of digits the SKUs have
     preg_match( '/ [\d]{' . $sku_digits . '} /', $product_name, $match );
     if ( $match ) {
         $sku = trim( $match[0] );
     }     
     return $sku;
}
```

but I found out, that the number in product text can be between 4-10 digits. I need to extract the number and remove 0 from beginning of numer, if its there. 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is actually very easy to fix, use the regex `\d+` to get matches with 1 or more numbers:

```
<?php

function my_get_sku($product_name) 
{
    if (empty($product_name))
        return 0;

    preg_match('/\d+/', $product_name, $match);
    if ($match !== false)
        return +$match[0]; // + will remove leading 0

    return 0;
}

echo my_get_sku('Lego creator 010270 Car V1 cool');
```

Returns `10270`

Answer (score 0):

Where in the original code it used `$sku_digits`, this is just the number of digits (it was made into `{5}` in the regex).  Instead, you need to change this to `{4,10}` to indicate the number of characters you want.

It also checks the first digit if it is a 0, and only removes this first digit if it is 0.

I've also changed the hardcoded spaces to be `\b` which is a word boundary so it will match with a `,` just after it (as in the example)

```
function my_get_sku( $product_name = "" ) {
    $sku = 0;                       // if no SKU is found, return 0
    preg_match( '/\b[\d]{4,10}\b/', $product_name, $match );
    if ( $match ) {
        $sku = trim( $match[0] );
        if ( $sku[0] == '0' ){
            $sku = substr($sku, 1);
        }
    }
    return $sku;
}

echo my_get_sku("Lego 2 creator 0102704, Car V1 cool");
```

gives (it ignores the 2 earlier as it is to short)

```
102704
```